# Laravel connecting to other database which not used

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

hi friends i am working on laravel and mysql database if 2 project work simultaneously on system then problem is occurre
example :

1. laravel_project_1 with database_1
2. laravel_project_2 with database_2
   then laravel_project_2 connecting to database_1 which is not valid.
   in env and config.database file I provide database name properly.
   please help.

Comment: Check the connection configuration.

Comment: Update your connection configuration here.